Determine Intersection Point Quadratic Bezier Curve and Plane
I need to compute the intersection point between a quadratic bezier curve and a plane. Thereby i have to solve the equation for the parameter t. The normal vector is in the dot product to the square bracket. However, this equation is genuinely complicated and thus my approach to solve for t is always incorrect. So could someone subtly help me solve the equation for t by documenting each step in the balance?
$$r(t) = (1-t)^2⋅P0+2(1-t)t⋅P1+t^2⋅P2$$,
$$E : n⋅(r-r0)=0$$,
$$n⋅[(1-t)^2⋅P0+2(1-t)t⋅P1+t^2⋅P2-r0]=0$$


Fig. 1 : A case with two points of intersection.
Your equation can be expressed under the form
$$(1-t)^2 \underbrace{(n⋅P_0)}_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}+2(1-t)t\underbrace{(n⋅P_1)}_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}}+t^2\underbrace{(n⋅P_2)}_{\gamma \in \mathbb{R}}-\underbrace{(n⋅r_0)}_{\delta \in \mathbb{R}}=0\tag{1}$$
which is in general a quadratic equation in variable $t$ with $2, 1$ or $0$ solutions.
This quadratic equation can be written in this way :
$$\underbrace{(\alpha-2 \beta + \gamma)}_{\epsilon}t^2+2(\beta-\alpha)t+(\alpha-\delta)=0\tag{2}$$
In the exceptional case where $\epsilon = 0$, we have no longer a quadratic equation but a first degree equation giving a single solution.
Edit :

About notations, let us take an example of dot product :

$$n⋅P_1=n^T P_1=\pmatrix{1&2&-4}\pmatrix{a\\b\\c}=1a+2b-4c \in \mathbb{R}$$

Besides, the solution(s) of quadratic eqn (2) can be given a simpler look than in your calculations ; Consider the discriminant that can be written under the form :

$$\Delta = \beta^2 +\delta \epsilon - \alpha \gamma \tag{1}$$
Then, classicaly :

two solutions when $\Delta>0$

a single solution when $\Delta=0$ (case of tangency to the plane)

no (real) solution when $\Delta<0$


In the first case, here are the two solutions :
$$t=\frac{\alpha - \beta\pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{\epsilon} $$
($\epsilon$ and $\Delta$ have been defined above.)

A different approach could have been possible. One can use the fact that the Bezier curve is planar : it lies in a plane (P') (defined by the three points $P_0,P_1,P_2$). Let (L) be the intersection line between this plane (P') and the initial plane (P) which exists, set apart the exceptional case where (P) and (P') are parallel. And the issue is reduced to testing whether or not line (L) intersects the Bezier curve or not.


That sounds convincing! But how can i solve this equation for the variable t?
$(α−2β+γ)t2+2(β−α)t+(α−δ)=0$

As a quadratic equation...

Is this the proper procedure and the proper outcome formula? And is it permissible to reduce the scalar product in the fraction at the end of my calculation? The following links lead to the pictures of my calculation:
link
link

I have had a look at your calculation : take care, in the second page, you simplify by n* : you aren't allowed to do this because it isn't an ordinary product but a dot product. A proof that this operation doesn't work is that after this simplification you are with a quotient vector/vector which in general is meaningless.

If I have some time (tomorrow), I will show you the computation.

Amazing! Can't wait to see the proper solution ... I cherish your help.

Edit written...
